# SAS: optimize inner join with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I am working on a query that goes something like this

```
    PROC SQL;
        CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE AS 
        SELECT A.* FROM TABLE1 AS A 
        INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B 
        ON (A.ACCOUNT = B.ACCOUNT OR A.CARDNO = B.CARDNO)
    QUIT;
```

However this is very slow. I get a warning saying that it is performing multiple cartesian products that cannot be optimized. So i would like to know if there is a better way to perform this operation. Maybe using a data step or rewriting the query in a different way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using **OR** when applying the join.

Try this:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE AS 
    SELECT A.* 
    FROM TABLE1 AS A 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B 
    ON A.ACCOUNT = B.ACCOUNT

    UNION

    SELECT A.* 
    FROM TABLE1 AS A 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS B 
    ON A.CARDNO = B.CARDNO;
QUIT;
```